# How to create a bar chart with a fixed y-axis value in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have just been learning Shiny for a week. I checked the function of ggplot2, but I didn't find the solution till now.
Now the output bar chart looks like this:

[image: What I want]

Whenever I change the value of the slider bar, the chart will also change, but for its y-axis, I want its value to always be fixed (such as 0 to 20000).

Now after I slide the slider bar, it will automatically change proportionally (such as 0 to 6000). In this case, the user will not realize how much the data has changed.

[image: After changed the value]

This is part of my code of the plot:

```
    q=ggplot(meantb_bar,aes(x = yi, y = Error_Square))+ 
      
      geom_bar(stat = "identity",fill="deepskyblue3") +

      labs(x = "yi", y = "(y_i-y^)^2")+ #useless for this question

      geom_text(aes(label = Error_Square)) #useless for this question

     ggplotly(q,width=500)
```

Comment: `ggplot2::coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,20000))`? (add that to your `ggplot(.)` sequence.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ylim` of ggplot to fix the y range:

```
q=ggplot(meantb_bar,aes(x = yi, y = Error_Square))+ 
      
      geom_bar(stat = "identity",fill="deepskyblue3") +

      labs(x = "yi", y = "(y_i-y^)^2")+ #useless for this question

      geom_text(aes(label = Error_Square)) +#useless for this question 
      ylim(0, 20000)

     ggplotly(q,width=500)
```